# Ruby - Spaceship operator won't work in a block for .sort

Tags: ruby, sorting, comparison

I'm getting an error when attempting to use the spaceship operator with non alpha-numeric characters in the sort function.

```
word = "out-classed"
letters = word.downcase.split('')
letters.sort! do |x, y|
  if y < 'a'
    next
  else
   value = x <=> y
  end
end
```

I'm getting `ArgumentError: comparison of String with String failed`, and I'm almost positive this happens with the spaceship operator and not the < comparison.

The interesting part is that when I do this same comparison in irb outside of the context of a sort block, the comparison works. It also works when the word variable only consists of letters.

Can anybody help me to understand why this doesn't work in this specific context alone?

Comment: It's a good question because it's important for you and others to understand why you cannot do what you'd like to to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `next` you need to return 0, 1 or -1. Try this:

```
word = "out-classed"
letters = word.downcase.split('')
letters.sort! do |x, y|
  if y < 'a'
    0
  else
   value = x <=> y
  end
end
```

Comment: This is working for everything except for closing periods ('.'). So, for example, the sentence "I'm going to do this." comes out as "i'm ggino ot do .hist" Maybe this is outside of the scope of the original question, but do you know why?

Comment: It isn't useful here, but just in case: `next 0` would also work.

Comment: Edit: nvm, this is outside the scope of the original question.

Comment: @steenslag You're not supposed to use `next` in these sorts of functions. You're expected to return `-1`, `0` or `1` only.

Comment: The `value =` part is completely useless here. In fact the whole thing could be collapsed to: `y < 'a' ? 0 : x <=> y`

Comment: @tadman So there's no 'value' in setting `x <=> y` to a variable at all unless I'm going to call it later?

Comment: There is no reason to set `value` to the result of the `<=>` comparison, unless you want only the result of the very last loop, which won't tell you much that is useful. You'd either want all comparisons, or you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Since you have not defined `value` prior to `sort`'s block, `value`'s scope is confined to the block.  If you reference `value` outside the block an "undefined local variable or method" exception will be raised.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Please see my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

If you attempt to sort a collection, `x<=>y` must return 0, 1 or -1 for every pair of elements of the collection. If `<=>` is defined artificially for some pairs (e.g., `'a'<=>'-' #=> 0` and `'-'<=>'a' #=> 0`), your sort may return erroneous results.

This is because sort algorithms do not necessarily evaluate all pairs of elements in the collection. If, for example, it finds that:

```
'a' <=> 'b' #=> 0
```

and

```
'b' <=> 'c' #=> 0
```

it will conclude that:

```
`a` <=> `c` #=> 0
```

because the collection being sorted must satisfy *transitivity*: `x <== z` if `x <= y` and `y <= z`.

For example, if the collection is the array `['z', '-', 'a']` and it finds that `'z' <= '-'` and `'-' <= 'a'`, it will conclude that `'z' <= 'a'` (and not evaluate `'z' <=> 'a'`).

That's why:

```
['z', '-', 'a'].sort { |x,y| p [x,y]; (y < 'a') ? 0 : x<=>y }
  #-> ["z", "-"]
  #-> ["-", "a"]
  #=> ["z", "-", "a"]
```

doesn't work. You have two choices:

Remove the offending elements before sorting:

```
['z', '-', 'a'].select { |c| ('a'..'z').cover?(c) }.
                sort { |x,y| (y < 'a') ? 0 : x<=>y }
  #=> ["a", "z"]
```

or sort all elements of the collection:

```
['z', '-', 'a'].sort
  #=> ["-", "a", "z"]
```

If the collection contains non-comparable elements (e.g., `[1,2,'cat']`), you only choice is to remove elements from the array until all remaining elements are comparable.

Comment: I'm leaving the selected answer as is because it did very directly answer the question. Upvote on this, however, because it's a very complete discussion of the subject. Incidentally, it helped me to solve the broader issue I was working on. Thank you!!

Comment: Upvote from me too, this is detail I was not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here

```
if y < 'a'
  next
else
  ...
```

`sort` method expects you to return a comparison value between **every** pair, so when you call `next` without returning anything, it says that comparison failed.

Try e.g. this:

```
if y < 'a'
  1
else
  value = x <=> y
end
```

Comment: This example is the default case of sort!, so you could really just say `letters.sort!` and have the same results

Comment: It looks like setting the value to 1 leads to punctuation characters being moved to before the text. What's your reasoning in using 1 as opposed to 0?

Comment: No reasoning at all, simply stating that the value returned should be `1`, `0` or `-1`, depending on how you want to sort this :)

Comment: ahh, I see. For practical purposes 0 is what I was looking for, but good thinking on making it widely useful.

Comment: `['z', '-', '-', 'a'].sort { |x,y| p [x,y]; (y < 'a') ? 0 : x<=>y } #=> ["z", "-", "-", "a"]` after printing `["z", "-"]`, `["-", "a"]` and `["-", "-"]`.